# How to access files in another folder in Vscode?

Tags: python, file, streamlit

So I have 2 folders in my project. Streamlit folder and data folder. A program that I have in Streamlit needs to access an image in data folder. How do I access these?

I tried

```
streamlit.image("data/image.jpeg", width=680)
```

This threw No such file or directory: error.

Comment: editor unimportant, add a tag for the language you are using

Comment: I have added the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
streamlit.image("../data/image.jpeg", width=680)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do needed something similar when I was making a script for sending bunch of emails with different images to recipients. What i did was:

#jpg can be tif or any other file type. I used *.tif, because i needed a list of images.

```
import glob
target_folder = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Username\\Destination\\Folder\\filename.jpg")

def open_image_attachment():
    image_list = []

    for one_image in target_folder:
        attachment = open(one_image, 'rb')
        file_name = os.path.basename(one_image)
        part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(attachment.read())
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                         'attachment', 
                         filename = file_name)
        image_list.append(part)
    return image_list
```